# only two Images are coming in Viewpager rest are blank which is present in a recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview

I am loading images in a viewpager which is present in a custom recyclerview but all images are not coming in the imagview only first two images are coming I have debugged it total 6 images are coming from the api url

Here is my viewpager adapter code

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    String url = context.getResources().getString(R.string.URL) + "media/" + imageUrls[position];

    Picasso.get()
            .load(url)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(imageView);
    container.addView(imageView);

    return imageView;
}
```

Here is my part of recyclerview

```
  @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    profiles profile = getItem(position);
    //image stuff
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cards, parent, false);
    }
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager userImageViewPager;
    userImageViewPager = convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImageViewPager);

    String[] imageUrls = new String[]{};
    if (profile.getImages() != null) {
        imageUrls = profile.getImages();
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(context, imageUrls);
        userImageViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    }
```

can anyone help me out i have been stuck for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call

```
userImageViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(imageUrls.length - 1)
```

after/before setting viewpageradapter